How to present findings from the mcmc_areas() and conditional_effects using r brms and bayesplot packages?
I am fairly new to bayesian statistics but have really fallen in love with what it can do and how it presents findings compared to frequentist statistics especially for categorical or ordinal datasets. However one thing I am having trouble with when presenting the data is what the axis means on the plots that I want to use (particularly mcmc_area or conditional_effects in R). Providing basic reproducible code followed by what I interpret the outcome to be.
library(tidyverse)
library(brms)
library(bayesplot)

model<-mtcars%>%
  mutate(gear = factor(gear))%>%
  brm(data = ., vs~0+gear, family = bernoulli())

mcmc_areas(model,
           prob = 0.89,
            pars = c("b_gear3","b_gear4","b_gear5"))

conditional_effects(model)

This produces a model that treats the number of gears as a factor and uses the type of engine (V or straight) as a boolean yes or no. Now from reading some helpful papers, resources, and posts but it is not quite clicking for me when presenting the findings. I am including the two plot outputs from the code provided above.
mcmc_areas plot
conditional_effects plot
Now my interpretation of the conditional effects plot is that the y axis demonstrates the predicted frequency of vs based on the gear. A 4 gear engine has the highest predicted probability of having a V shaped engine (~0.8) compared to the other two. The difference between gear 3 and gear 4 is "statistically significant" (I know that's not words you use in bayesian stats and can consider something like ROPE ) based on the non overlapping credible interval bars. I can then follow that up with the mcmc areas plot and see the same thing given there is no overlap between the 89% HDI(?) regions. Gear 4 is also higher in a notable way compared to gear 5 but not as much.
Is that interpretation correct? Or am I missing some big estimations or functions that would help show these better? Likewise, what in the world is the x axis on the mcmc plot. I am expecting this question to come up, but do not have a definitive answer as to what the scale is or what a negative vs positive value means. I know it can be interpreted in terms of direction (gear 4 higher than gear 5 or 3) but what does gear 5 having a median value of roughly -1.5 mean? I cannot find a definitive answer and am open to reading more resources or having a discussion.
Thank you for your time
